# Optimizing C code for Sparc for smaller image size using gcc

Tags: gcc, optimization, embedded, compiler-optimization, sparc

I have some C code that I trying to compile for a Sparc V8 based system with highly constrained resources. I am using gcc and I would like to ask the following questions.

1) Besides turning off debugging (-g flag) what other options do I have to reduce the compile object size?

2) ARM has a thumb mode, does Sparc have anything similar?

3) What other compiler options (or even C code tricks) can be used to reduce a compiled binary object size.

Once again I am using gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile with -Os. It means optimize for size. 
If some parts of the code are supposed to run as fast as possible, you can use `__attribute__((optimize("-O2")))` to optimize an specific function for speed.

See the following link for explanation of optimization flags: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `__attribute__(optimize(...))`, the documentation describes it as "This attribute should be used for debugging purposes only. It is not suitable in production code."

Comment: Also, inlining can sometimes reduce code size, and `-Os` already tells the compiler not to inline when it would increase the size.

Answer (score 1):

1) As Mat said: Use -Os flag for code size reduction

2) No. Have a look at the manual here: http://www.gaisler.com/doc/sparcv8.pdf

3) Read this article: https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/Reducing-Contiki-OS-firmware-size
It is code size reduction recommendations for Contiki OS project written by a very experienced engineer. Contiki OS is an embedded C project usually compiled with GCC, so it applies to your problem.